# Does Smalltalk support local variable in blocks? If not, why?

Tags: closures, smalltalk, block

I heard that Smalltalk doesn't support local variable in blocks. Is this true? If it is, why doesn't Smalltalk support local variables? And can I still assume it as equal with *closures*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the smalltalk platform you choose. Basically you have block local variables on all smalltalk platforms. There are IMHO two kinds of implementations. If there isn't a full closure support the local variables are shared with the local variables of the method surrounding that block. For this you need to know how to work-around some problems. For full closure support local variables are there and work as you might expect.

Squeak and Pharo used to have locals that are shared with the method. Nowadays a VM with full closure support exists and Pharo supports this fully and I think Squeak does, too. I think gemstone hasn't full closure support. I don't know about VaST and VisualWorks.

You can always test it by doing something like the following:

```
((1 to: 5) collect: [:i| 
    [ | local | local := i ]])
        collect: [:each| each value]
```

Here you only get

```
#(1 2 3 4 5)
```

if there is full closure support and

```
#(5 5 5 5 5)
```

if the | local | is shared with the method.

Comment: VisualWorks and ST/X implement full closures

Comment: "good" is relative.  Closures are a bit more expensive, and nobody needed them in Smalltalk-80, which ran just fine on a 1 Mhz (note: 1/1000 of a GHz for you kids :) machine.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean a block local variable, like `today` in this example:

```
10 timesRepeat: 
  [| today | 
  today := Date today. 
  Transcript cr; show: today printString]
```

Answer (score 0):

huh? where did you hear that? try this code:

```
block := [
  x := 10.
  x printNl.
].

block value.
```

it should output 10.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid smalltalk. While you are using printNl I assume you are using gnu smalltalk, right? I would wonder if there isn't the necessity to declare locals like this: | x | inside the block or outside of it

Comment: Indeed, I only use GNU Smalltalk (don't really like the other Smalltalk, too GUIsh). Err... it's not necessary to declare in GST, but I guess I should do so.

Comment: You probably should. Otherwise it isn't clear if x belongs to inside of the block or outside. I don't know the gnu smalltalk semantics here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VA Smalltalk supports them.

Comment: For comments and additions you should add a comment instead of creating a new answer.